# Changing form of an equation in an integral

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I know this:

$$ \int \sqrt{a^2-x^2} =\frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{a^2-x^2}+a^2\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) $$

I have to solve:

$$ \int \sqrt{5-x^2-4x} $$

I understand i should write 
$$ 5-x^2-4x $$
in a similar form of
$$ a^2-x^2 $$

What's the correct way to change the form of the expression?

Once i have this solution:
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(9\sqrt{-x^2-4x+5}+9\arcsin\left(\frac{3}{x+2}\right)\right )$$
I have to calculate the definite integral between 1 and -2 , but replacing -2 give me:
$$ \arcsin\left( \frac {3} {0}\right) $$
how to deal with this?

Comment: $\sqrt{3^2-(x+2)^2}$ then set $u=x+2$

Comment: i need to understand the thinking process, i've already checked the result on wolfram

Comment: Complete the square.

Comment: Ok. $5-(x^2+4x)=5-(x^2+4x+2^2-2^2)=5-(x^2+4x+4)+4=9-(x+2)^2$

Comment: Note $-1 \le \left(\frac{3}{x+2}\right)\le 1\implies x\ge 1$ or $x\le -5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider $$-x^2-4x+5$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -(x^2+4x) + 5 $$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -(x^2+4x+4)+5+4$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow -(x+2)^2+9$$

Now the integral becomes

$$ \int \sqrt{-x^2-4x+5} dx = \int \sqrt{-(x+2)^2+9}$$

Now let $u = x+2  \Leftrightarrow du=dx$

$$ \int \sqrt{9-u^2} = \int \sqrt{3^2-u^2} $$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, but if i simply replace in the result a=(x+2) and x=3 isn't the same? and it's looks easier

Comment: then $a^2-x^2=(x+2)^2-3^2=x^2+4x+4-9=x^2+4x-5\ne 5-x^2-4x$

Comment: i don't understand why in the exercisethey give me that previous integral result if i can't replace